# Filter arrays with predicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I want to filter 2 lists. I'm having list A that contains many items and list B contains items that I want to track. So list A must be filtered by list B.

I tried like this:

```
NSArray * trackings = [[BeaconDAO sharedInstance] loadData];

NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"macAddress IN %@", trackings];
NSArray *filteredObjects = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

NSLog(@"FilteredObject count = %d", [filteredObjects count]);
```

Where trackings is a NSArray with a custom model that I wrote with a property macAddress. 
The filteredObjects is always zero so something is wrong.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Does `trackings` contain and array of pure mac addresses? Or does `trackings` contain an array of objects that contain a mac address?

Comment: An array of objects that contain mac address.

Comment: Ah, in that case @Wain's answer is what you need. I knew there was a way of doing that but couldn't think what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
NSArray *filteredObjects = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(ESTBeacon *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    BOOL isInArray = NO;
    for (BeaconModel *beacon in trackings) {
        if([beacon.macAddress isEqualToString:evaluatedObject.macAddress]){
            isInArray = YES;
        }
    }
    return isInArray;
}]];
```

With a block to compare the items.

Answer (score 1):

From your description (seeing a log of the array contents would be useful) you are supplying objects to match against instead of the contained mac addresses. Instead, do:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"macAddress IN %@", [trackings valueForKey:@"macAddress"]];
```

so that you are filtering against the addresses (cutting out the container objects).